# Which fuse blade type should I use for Honda Accord 2001? Regular size or Mini or Low-Profile Mini

Tags: honda, accord, fuse

The radio and the power socket are completely off, I am reading that the fuse #9 (20A) may be blown up.

I am not sure which Fuse blade type I should use to replace for Honda Accord 2001?  Regular size  or Mini or Low-Profile Mini. [Blade types from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuse_(automotive)#Blade_type]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's probably an ATM fuse if it's in the MICU (under-dash fusebox).

Comment: Why not just pull one out and look at it? The Wiki page you have listed shows a pretty good representative picture of what the fuses look like. They are very recognizable from each other.

Comment: Thanks Ben, Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, I checked the fuse box and this is an Mini one